# How to can save data in opendaylight?

Tags: sdn, opendaylight

I want create application for opendaylight controller, i need save time,number and ip address but i not know how to can save data,or can create database for save data in opendaylight?

Answer (score 1):

MDSAL is OpenDaylight's model-driven database that ODL apps typically use for such things. I think if you grep around for DataBroker objects you should see lots of examples.

Comment: Take a look at the toaster example in the controller project and the associated wiki page: https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:Toaster_Step-By-Step